# How to compare MySQL int value within the query without fetching it

Tags: php, mysql, session

Finally i give up as i have tried many examples that did not work for me...
Basically i want to query a DB like below.

```
    $main_query=$con->query("SELECT USERID FROM SUPERDATATABLE WHERE USERID=$_SESSION[USERID] AND scores>50")or die('Oops, Failed 2 work!');

    if(mysqli_num_rows($main_query)>0){
    echo 'it worked';
    }else{
           echo 'sorry, i cant';
         }
```

Now i explicitly set scores greater than 100 so i know it is supposed to echo **it worked** instead of **sorry, i cant**.
I started the session and when I echo the session ($_SESSION['USERID']), i see that it is set and also not empty, but this statement is maybe not supported by MySQL.

somebody please help me

Comment: Where is `$looper` being set?

Comment: Looks like `$looper` should be `$main_query`, or vice versa.

Comment: If you just want to know whether the data exists, and you don't need to fetch the results, I suggest using `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT USERID`. This way only one row is ever returned, instead of wasting time sending back lots of results just so you can get the count.

Comment: You're wide open for SQL injection. Look into prepared statements and binding parameters. It will fix any quoting issues that may be popping up in your query.

Answer (score 0):

yes of course you can query a db like this, but you can't use an array within double quotes like this. it should be `"${_SESSION['USERID']}"`

Comment: The brace goes on the other side of the dollar sign.

Comment: Other than the SQL injection angle, there's nothing wrong with the way they did it. Array keys should be unquoted when using them within a double-quote string without brackets, and in many situations, including this one, the complex syntax isn't necessary.